# Fair dice throwing, expected value

Tags: probability

We throw a standard fair dice until we threw $5$ and then $2,4$ or $6$ (not necessarily  one after another). What is the expected value and variation of number of throws (let it be $X$)?

I was thinking about using the definition of expected value here, but to do that I need $\mathbb{P}(X=k)$ and I just have no clue how to easily express that probability.

Comment: What is the meaning of "get 5 and even number of throws"?

Comment: Is it not true that P(K=1)=0,P(K=2)=1/6,P(K=3)=0,P(K=4)=(1/6)(1-P(K=2)),...? Since the result on odd numbered throws make no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the random number of rolls needed to obtain the first $5$, and let $Y$ be the random number of rolls needed to obtain the first instance of $2$, $4$, or $6$ after the first $5$.  Then $Z = X+Y$ is the random variable for the total number of rolls needed to observe the event of interest.  Clearly, $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so $\mathrm{E}[Z] = \mathrm{E}[X] + \mathrm{E}[Y]$ and $\mathrm{Var}[Z] = \mathrm{Var}[X] + \mathrm{Var}[Y]$.  We then need only characterize the distributions of $X$ and $Y$.  To this end, note that $X$ must be a geometric random variable:  for each die roll is independent of any previous die roll, and the probability of obtaining a $5$ on a given die roll is constant, $p = 1/6$.  Thus $$\Pr[X = x] = (1-p)^{x-1}p, \quad x = 1, 2, 3, \ldots.$$  Similarly, $Y$ is also geometric, but with probability $\pi = 1/2$, since the probability of rolling any even number on a single roll is $3/6 = 1/2$.  From this information, it is straightforward to obtain the mean and variance of $Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Here $X=Y+Z$ where $Y$ stands for the number of throws needed for
throwing the first $5$ and $Z$ for the number of throws needed for
throwing a first even number after that event.

Then $Y$ and $Z$ both have [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). $Y$ with parameter
$\frac{1}{6}$ and $Z$ with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$, and:

$$\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}Y+\mathbb{E}Z$$

$Y$ and $Z$ are independent so that:

$$\text{Var}X=\text{Var}Y+\text{Var}Z$$

Answer (score 0):

A more general answer to the question about expectation is to observe that this is a Markov chain. We have a state 1 before we've hit a 5, a state 2 between hitting a 5 and 2/4/6, and a state 3 where we have hit the 5 and then the 2/4/6. In this specific case we can decouple the problem, because we must always pass through state 2 and we never go back to state 1 after reaching state 2. If either of those fails, we can still do the following.

Let our chain be denoted by $X_n$, acting on a state space $\{ 1,2,3 \}$ as defined above. Define $\tau = \inf \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : X_n = 3 \}$ and let $v(x) = \mathbb{E}(\tau | X_0 = x)$. Then $v(3) = 0$ and we have

$$v(x) = \sum_{y=1}^3 p_{xy} \left ( v(y) + 1 \right )$$

for $x=1,2$, where $p_{xy}$ is the transition probability between state $x$ and state $y$. Noting that $\sum_{y=1}^3 p_{xy} = 1$ we can write this as a linear system by moving all the $v(y)$ terms to the left side:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1-p_{11} & -p_{12} & -p_{13} \\ -p_{21} & 1-p_{22} & -p_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} v(1) \\ v(2) \\ v(3) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Then in the case of this problem, $p_{11} = 5/6,p_{12}=1/6,p_{13}=0,p_{21}=0,p_{22}=1/2,p_{23}=1/2$ and you want to find $v(1)=\mathbb{E}(\tau | X_0 = 1)$.

If we multiply through by $-1$, the matrix on the left side becomes the *generator* of our Markov chain, and we get the form $(Av)(x) = -1$, which appears in much more general contexts including processes taking place on a continuous state space.